Types of singularities
I am confused about the types of singularities. According to my limited knowledge there are two types of singularity. One is space like singularity ( a curvature singularity enclosed within a null hypersurface called event horizon and is not visible) the second one is naked singularity (curvature singularity without any event horizon and thus it is visible). Further naked singularity had two types one is null like other is time like. But I'm confused about these two. How can we determine whether a naked singularity is null like or timelike though the curvature invariants are infinite at r=0!
P.s: In literature some naked singularities are timelike e.g JMN1 singularity.

How can a singularity exist in a physical object?

Here is a PBS video that might help - Singularities Explained | Infinite Series

@Wookie Singularities don’t exist despite a widespread obsession.

@zahra The Big Bang is a spacelike singularity without a horizon. The Kerr ringularity is timelike behind two horizons. Your list is incomplete.

@safesphere Obsession: The singular fragrance from Schwarzschild & Co.
